# HttpResponseMessage serialization

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, datacontractserializer

I have a class with 2 attributes. One attribute is a HttpResponseMessage and I need to serialize this. I hade made a [DataContract] over the class and a [DataMember] over the HttpResponse.
Here is the class:

```
[DataContract]
public class ResponseItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public HttpResponseMessage ResponseMessage { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public CacheInfoItem CacheInfo { get; set; }
}
```

the problem is when I test it then I get this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred 
in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Type 'System.Net.Http.StreamContent' cannot be serialized. 
Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its 
members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a    
collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft 
.NET Framework documentation for other supported types.
```

what is wrong?

EDIT: I have a save method:

```
public static async Task SaveObjectAsync(Object toBeSaved, string fileName = null, 
StorageLocation storageLocation = StorageLocation.Local, SerializerType serializerType = 
SerializerType.DataContractJson)
    {
        Type type = toBeSaved.GetType();
        fileName = getFileName(fileName, type, serializerType);
        StorageFolder folder = getStorageFolder(storageLocation);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        Serializer serializer = getSerializer(serializerType, type);
        serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, toBeSaved);
        StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            await fileStream.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
```

but it looks that the serializer can't handle the HttpResponseMessage

Comment: Why would you think that this type can be serialized? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't really know if it can be serialized. I want to save the responsemessage

Comment: So pull the message out, then serialize the message. Don't be lazy and try to serialize the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Add `[Serialize]` on top of the class to make it serializable.

EDIT: Did not know it's for Win RT. In that case you need to create serialize-helper class:

Use this class as the serialized-class:

```
class LocalStorage
{
    private static List<object> _data = new List<object>();


    public static List<object> Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set { _data = value; }
    }

    private const string filename = "cats.xml";

    static async public Task Save<T>()
    {
        await Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool.RunAsync((sender) => LocalStorage.SaveAsync<T>().Wait(), Windows.System.Threading.WorkItemPriority.Normal);
    }

    static async public Task Restore<T>()
    {
            await Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool.RunAsync((sender) => LocalStorage.RestoreAsync<T>().Wait(), Windows.System.Threading.WorkItemPriority.Normal);
    }

    static async private Task SaveAsync<T>()
    {
        StorageFile sessionFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        IRandomAccessStream sessionRandomAccess = await sessionFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        IOutputStream sessionOutputStream = sessionRandomAccess.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
        var sessionSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<object>), new Type[] { typeof(T) });
        sessionSerializer.WriteObject(sessionOutputStream.AsStreamForWrite(), _data);
        await sessionOutputStream.FlushAsync();
    }

    static async private Task RestoreAsync<T>()
    {
        StorageFile sessionFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        if (sessionFile == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        IInputStream sessionInputStream = await sessionFile.OpenReadAsync();
        var sessionSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<object>), new Type[] { typeof(T) });
        _data = (List<object>)sessionSerializer.ReadObject(sessionInputStream.AsStreamForRead());
    }
}
```

And the essential code to use the helper class:

```
namespace SerializeListWinRT
{

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Cat> _cats = new ObservableCollection<Cat>();

    public ObservableCollection<Cat> Cats
    {
        get { return _cats; }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ClearLists();
        AddCatsToList();
        CreateNewCat();
    }

    private async void AddCatsToList()
    {
        await LocalStorage.Restore<Cat>();
        SetCatList();
    }

    private void ClearLists()
    {
        Cats.Clear();
        LocalStorage.Data.Clear();
    }

    private void SetCatList()
    {
        foreach (var item in LocalStorage.Data)
        {
            _cats.Add(item as Cat);
        }
    }

    public Cat NewCat { get; set; }

    private void CreateNewCat()
    {
        NewCat = new Cat();
    }

    private void AddNewCat()
    {
        _cats.Add(new Cat {Name = NewCat.Name, About = NewCat.About});
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewCat();
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewCat();
        SaveList();
    }

    private void SaveList()
    {
        LocalStorage.Data.Add(NewCat);
        LocalStorage.Save<Cat>();
    }

}
}
```

The `LocalStorage.Save<Cat>();` serializes and saves it, which sounds like what you want.

Reference: http://irisclasson.com/2012/07/09/example-metro-app-winrt-serializing-and-deseralizing-objects-to-storagefile-and-localfolder-using-generics-and-asyncawait-threading/

Comment: So how do you suggest implementing it for .Net classes?

Comment: It is for WinRT and I can't set a [Serialize]

Comment: See my Edit in the original post

Comment: Do you get a erorr message or what happens?

Comment: I want to save the ResponseItem. But when I want save this item I get the error

Comment: I mean what do you mean with "but it looks that the serializer can't handle the HttpResponseMessage". What happened when you tried my solution?

Comment: I mean that when I set the HttpResponseMessage in my ResponseItem to [IgnoreDataMember than I have no error. I don't really know which part in your solution is for the serialization because I don't want to use another save method.